# setting flag in XSLT to detect the first time through a loop

Tags: variables, xslt, foreach, umbraco

New to xslt.  Using it in umbraco, so it's version 1.0.

Trying to insert separators between links in an inline footer list, so will put them before each link except the first one.  This is a simple programming problem, where you set a flag to 0 outside the loop, then once in, you test if the flag is 1 and if it's not, you skip adding a separator before the link.  As the last bit in the first pass through the loop, you set the flag to 1.

How can I accomplish this in xslt?  I'm a bit flummoxed by the syntax and reading that once a variable value is set you can't change it.  Anyone have a simple exmaple?

Comment: Please provide sample input XML.

Comment: Show your input, XSLT code and expected output. XSLT does not have mutable variables in the sense that other procedural languages do, so "setting a flag for the first time through a loop" is not possible in that manner.

Comment: Also please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on asking good questions.

Comment: the input is through an umbraco macro call.  there is no xml, is there?

Comment: also, this doesn't have anything to do with what's passed in.  I just need to locally set a variable that, as the for-each loop parses the links, tests that variable.  I have the links parsed fine, I just need to tell it not to put the first '|' before the link.

Comment: neil1967, There must be a source XML document -- otherwise what are you processing? To see the source XML document, just process it with the *identity template*

Answer (score 4):

**Here is a simple example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pBase" select="'http://myBase.com/'"/>

 <xsl:template match="num">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
  <a href="{$pBase}{.}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<a href="http://myBase.com/01">01</a>, <a href="http://myBase.com/02">02</a>, <a href="http://myBase.com/03">03</a>, <a href="http://myBase.com/04">04</a>, <a href="http://myBase.com/05">05</a>, <a href="http://myBase.com/06">06</a>, <a href="http://myBase.com/07">07</a>, <a href="http://myBase.com/08">08</a>, <a href="http://myBase.com/09">09</a>, <a href="http://myBase.com/10">10</a>
```

**and it is displayed in the browser as**:

[01](http://myBase.com/01), [02](http://myBase.com/02), [03](http://myBase.com/03), [04](http://myBase.com/04), [05](http://myBase.com/05), [06](http://myBase.com/06), [07](http://myBase.com/07), [08](http://myBase.com/08), [09](http://myBase.com/09), [10](http://myBase.com/10)

**Explanation:**

1. XSLT is a functional language -- among other things this means that variables, once defined, cannot be changed.
2. The standard XPath **[`position()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-position)** function can be used to check if the position of the current node has a specific value.
3. The **[builtin XSLT templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule)** are used and the one that matches an element has this body: `<xsl:apply-templates/>` . This is an abbreviation for: `<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>` and applies templates to all node children of the current node -- in document order.
4. Because we have specified `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`, the whitespace-only children of any element has been stripped during the parsing of the XML document. This leaves only non-white-space children nodes of the top element `nums` and they are all `num` elements.
5. The value of the `position()` function inside a template is the position of the current node in the node-list formed when the `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction is executed. This means that the value of the `position()` function inside the template matching `num` is 1 when the first `num` element is processed, 2 when the 2nd `num` element is processed, ..., 10 when the 10th `num` element is processed.
6. The generated output for all `num` elements where the value of `position()` is greater than 1 starts with the string ", " -- exactly as per the requirements of this question. For the first `num` element the string ", " isn't generated, because the value of `position()` in this case is 1.

Comment: @ABach, next time is yours :) But see the explanation.

Comment: One question: how did you get `position()` to output two digits? libxslt and Saxon seem to only output single digits.

Comment: @ABach, The two digits aren't the `position()` they are the string value of the current node.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as time in XSLT. You can't detect the "first time through a loop" because there is no concept of time, therefore no first time, in fact, it's not a loop in the traditional programming sense at all. All the items in the input list are conceptually processed in parallel. That's why you can't set variables for use in later iterations - there is no such thing as a "later iteration".

What you can do is to detect that you are processing the first item in the input sequence (or the first item in the input sequence after sorting, if you use xsl:sort). You do that with the test `position() = 1`.